# Post comment permission by content type and role

Tags: 7, users, comments

I want to only allow users of a specific role to be able to comment on a specific content type. The only current solution for this is using the "Comment Permissions" module which unfortunately is only available for Drupal 6 and hasn't been updated for over a year.
I have seen some people saying that it's possible to do this by writing custom code however i haven't been able to find any examples of this. Does anyone here know how this could be done or at least point me in the right direction? I'm not good at php though i have some programming experience.

I was thinking that it would also be okay if i could allow users of a specific role to comment on nodes/content type where commenting has been closed if achieving it that way is simpler.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a chance to get a D7 version of the module. Please have a look at [this issue queue entry](http://drupal.org/node/1152576#comment-6158400).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days there is a D7 version of [Comment Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm). Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... enables control of commenting by user role and by node type. Additional user permissions for selected node types are added to the user access system so you can configure commenting with more control than Drupal core provides.